# Executable Jar File

Tags: java, eclipse, export

I know this has been asked a LOT, and I have tried probably 20-30 different methods from eclipse (Kepler, Ganymede, Galileo) , fatJar, netbeans, blueJ, command-line, and manual.

Basically, everytime I execute this it will create the Jar file (yay). When I click it, it will start up the game (yay!). But when I click start, it freezes (boo!).

I thought maybe it had something to do with the resource reading. However, on the start screen (which works in the executable jar) there is a resource background, and it gets read just fine. It isn't producing any errors (that I can tell). I cannot seem to run it command-line at all.

I put the code up on gitHub, but it is automatically ignoring my bin folder (not sure if that is a problem). I have probably tried every possible combination of export options on Eclipse, and it is always the same problem.

Of course, like all the other problems, it will run from the eclipse IDE when I click run, just not from the executable.

I have run across some people say to move the Resources Folder inside a package inside of src.I have yet to try that method mostly because there must be able to keep the resources folder separate from the src folder, and I would prefer to keep them that way.

https://github.com/Gostdreamer/DragonBash/tree/master/MyGame

Example of how I'm accessing resources (So you don't have to read all my code if you don't want to)

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Maps/level1-1Type.map");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

And:

```
tileset = ImageIO.read(getClass()
          .getResourceAsStream("/Tilesets/grasstileset4.gif"));
```

And:

```
BufferedImage spritesheet = ImageIO.read(getClass()
              .getResourceAsStream("/Sprites/Player/playersprites.gif"));
```

Some screenshots of the organization:

[image]

[image]

[image: I have tried with the jre library checked and unchecked]

I have tried with the jre library checked and unchecked

**Edit 1**
I found myself an error. This is new, this is from a fatJar compile using Eclipse Keplar and running it from command prompt

http://www.codesend.com/view/13b1bbf472f10880992f6fd096eae24b/

Using a codesend link so as not to bog down StackOverflow with lots of errors

**Edit 2**
[image]

Inside of the .jar

Comment: If I were you, i would use Maven (and the M2E Eclipse plugin) to create the .jar resource instead of using the built-in Eclipse export jar method.  It might simplify things for you or possibly make it easier to understand how your resources are getting loaded.

Comment: Alright...I just got Maven/M2E, and...have NO idea how to use it, been googling ever since. However, in the mean time, is there a way I can just change the path so that it runs for now?

Comment: You need to use the "maven-exec" plugin (call it using 'mvn.bat exec:java' ) and the "maven-jar-plugin" (using 'mvn.bat package' ).  It is a bit of a learning curve but if its too much for you you can still do it the way your doing now UNTIL you have learned to use Maven later.  You might also possibly consider using Gradle, which has similar usage but is not configured with confusing XML.

Comment: Yeah, I changed around the class paths, but I'm working on learning Maven now...it's pretty intense, but I can see how you said it would solve the problem. TY for the advice :)

Comment: There is some benefit to keeping it simple and not using Maven.  It depends on what you are doing.  For example, programmers who use Groovy, Python, or Scala don't use Maven to build their projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

I see what the problem is.

You are loading and/or packaging resources incorrectly, that's why they are coming up as `null`.

`/` is relative to your CLASSPATH, which when you build a single executable jar with everything in it, is the root of your jar.

---

Old answer:

To get errors to be displayed:

1. Make sure you start the jar from a Command Prompt.
2. If you have anything like this in your code,

   ```
   catch(Exception ex) {}
   ```

or anything else that suppresses exceptions, REMOVE IT, or if that does not seem possible, change it to:

```
catch(Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you have multiple threads, you may need to catch exceptions at the top level of your threads (this is not necessary for the main thread).

If all else fails, use `jstack`.

Comment: Alrighty, got myself some errors and uploaded them too. At the start it looks like it isn't getting a resource graphic, which seems to play into latter errors when it goes into animation since the graphic doesn't exist. Then it goes into more that I don't really get, but it shouldn't be popping resource errors with the Slugger, I don't understand :(

Comment: Alright, I'm sorry I kind of understand what you are saying, but what do I put in place of that so that it is getting the right location? I've never not used /

Comment: What's in your executable jar? Where are the resources located in the jar?

Comment: It puts everything in one folder

Comment: And what is that folder called?

Comment: Oi, I got it...I played with all of the paths to the resources until I found the one that made it work >.< But you were right, tyvm :)